# How to identify which is relevant information for audience and set right context in discussions?

Tags: software-industry, united-states, meetings

I am working as team lead for IT department of US based organization. My team consists team member from different vendors. Even I am also vendor to current organization.

In the meetings(Specifically one on one and other meetings and not while giving presentations) I always face difficult to identify relevant information to the audience and set context accordingly. I usually have lot of information when discussion occurs it is hard for me to identify relevant information to the audience and set proper context to the audience. Due to this some times the discussion are side tracked and deviated from right track. Some time it requires more time to achieve objective of the discussions. In some complex cases, I am not able to achieve the objective of the discussion. So I am looking for some methods or processes to identify most relevant information to the audience.

Hence my question is, How to identify most relevant information for the audience while I am speaking in work related discussions? And also based on that how can I set right context to start the discussion with right direction?

Comment: To those voting to close... difficult to answer well is not the same as too broad of a question.  This question is in scope and not so broad as to make it impossible to answer here.

Answer (score 5):

When giving presentations at work a number of factors about the audience should be taken into consideration such as: the goals for attending, degree of technical knowledge, and areas of technical skill. Finally, you should also strongly consider the goals of the presentation.

**Audience Goals for Attending**

Depending on how and to whom the presentation was marketed or who the invitations were sent for smaller groups, you may have a mixture of attendee goals. An audience composed primarily of leads and managers will want a high-level overview of the subject. Then, follow up with questions to dive into the areas that concern them.  If your audience is primarily managers, you should be prepared to speak about licensing options, processes and things like value-propositions.

**Audience' Degree of Technical Knowledge**

If the audience is composed primarily of developers (as opposed to managers), then a good deep-dive with practical on-hands examples and sourcecode would be better than an organization chart with responsiblities. How deep you go will depend on the degree of your audience's technical skill. Hard-core coders will want to talk about specific implementation details. Whereas the higher you go into the leadership, the less they care about that. Also, be sure to leave a nice QA session, to ensure you cover everything.

**Audience' Areas of Technical Skill**

When your audience is composed of individuals knowledgable of one particular technology or vendor, you will want to tailor your presentation to that technology. That doesn't mean you can't discuss other things, but use that technology basis as your foundation for comparison, and discussion. In the event that you're speaking about a contrasting, or competing technology, be prepared to compare and contrast technologies in an unbiased manner (or as much as is possible). Again, leave time for QA to make sure you get all  of the questions.

**Presentation Goals**

When presenting to groups of people, remember that you have to stay focused. It is very likely that a hard-core coder attending a meeting could get bored with all this talk about licensing and ask a question requiring a deep-dive. It is very fair to postpone the question to later (after the presentation), or simply guide the presentation back on-track. Usually, you can let tangental conversations go for a couple of minutes before guiding them back to the topic at hand.

Lastly, be prepared to take tangents that aren't the focus of the presentation, and offer to host a discussion about the tangents at a seperate time.  This respects the curiosity of the audience, while ensuring you can keep on your presentation schedule.